# Way to progressively overlap line plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a for loop from which I call a function grapher() which extracts certain columns from a dataframe (position and w, both continuous variables) and plots them. My code changes the Y variable (called w here) each time it runs and so I'd like to plot it as an overlay progressively. If I run the grapher() function 4 times for example, I'd like to have 4 plots where the first plot has only 1 line, and the 4th has all 4 overlain on each other (as different colours).

I've already tried points() as suggested in other posts, but for some reason it only generates a new graph.

```
grapher <- function(){
position.2L <- data[data$V1=='2L', 'V2']
w.2L <- data[data$V1=='2L', 'w']
plot(position.2L, w.2L)
points(position.2L, w.2L, col='green')
}


# example of my for loop #
for (t in 1:200){
#code here changes the 'w' variable each iteration of 't'
if (t%%50==0){
grapher()
  }
}
```

Comment: Calling `plot` will create a new plot each time. If you want to add to an existing plot, call `plot` once and then add lines using the `lines` function and points using the `points` function. When you first call `plot` you'll also need to set the desired ranges of the x and y axes using the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments. For example: `plot(NA, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(-5,20), xlab="", ylab="")`

Comment: Does this mean I need to create new variables each time my code runs? For example the above grapher() runs 4 times, would I need to store Y1, Y2, Y3 and Y4? If so, is there no other way to do this to prevent hardcoding variables?

Comment: The variables can be called anything, and can be the same names (but presumably with different values) each time through the loop, or different names.

Comment: Another approach would be to first generate the variables and store them in a matrix, then plot them all (or any subset) at once using `matplot()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing any details about your situation I can only assume something like this might be applicable.

```
# Example data set
d <- data.frame(V1=rep(1:2, each=6), V2=rep(1:6, 2), w=rep(1:6, each=2))

# Prepare the matrix we will write to.
n <- 200
m <- matrix(d$w, nrow(d), n)

# Loop progressively adding more noise to the data
set.seed(1)
for (i in 2:n) {
    m[,i] <- m[,i-1] + rnorm(nrow(d), 0, 0.05)
}

# We can now plot the matrix, selecting the relevant rows and columns
matplot(m[d$V1 == 1, seq(1, n, by=50)], type="o", pch=16, lty=1)
```

[image]